# Reference formatting without impacting its discoverabalitiy by services like Google Scholar

Tags: bibliographies, citing, google-scholar

Probably this forum is not the best fit for my question and I apologize for posting it here. However, I couldn't think of any better forum (please suggest if you know one.).

When citing some paper in a manuscript what fields of the BIBTEX we can change/remove without impacting the citation count done by services like Google Scholar?

In other words what are the fields in citations which Google Scholar like services count?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Have you considered posting to [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)?